# How to use PARI/GP for calculating the inverse of a power series?

Tags: array-formulas, pari-gp

I want to invert a power series with PARI/GP:
if `$y=a[1]*x+a[2]*x^2+...+O(x^N)$` is encoded by a given array, say `a=vector(N-1)`, I want PARI to produce the vector b such that `$x=b[1]*y+b[2]*y^2+...+O(y^N)$`.
This can be done [using the Bell polynomials](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/02/24/invert-power-series/). The Pari handbook has

```
Bell(k,n=-1)=
{
my(var(i)=eval(Str("X",i)));
my(x,v,dv);
v=vector(k,i,if(i==1,’E,var(i-1)));
dv=vector(k,i,if(i==1,’X*var(1)*’E,var(i)));
x=diffop(’E,v,dv,k)/’E;
if(n<0,subst(x,’X,1),polcoeff(x,n,’X))
}
```

producing e.g.

```
gp > Bell(3)
%3 = X1^3 + 3*X2*X1 + X3
```

But I have no idea how to use those, i.e. to attribute values to `X1, X2, ...` in a subsequent formula in Pari (in fact, I hardly understand how `eval()` and `subst()` work in the above formula!). That should be trivial for someone who knows... Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PARI has a built in function to do power series reversion, so there is no need to get into a low level implementation which is certainly very sub-optimal and complicated.

Example use:

```
serreverse( x / (1 + x)^2 + O(x^20))
```

A second example (based on an example in the link given in the question)

```
serreverse(atan(x + O(x^20)))
tan(x + O(x^20))
```

If your series is in a vector `v` you would first convert it to a power series and then call `serreverse`. For example:

```
serreverse(Ser(v))
```

To convert back to a vector later use the `Vec` function. When converting from a power series to a vector PARI will strip any leading zeros, which can be annoying. To prevent this there is a second argument which you typically give as `-n` or `-(n+1)` where `n` is the number of terms in the power series.

Comment: oh thank you, good to know! (The PARI jargon would be serreverse(atan(x + O(x^20))) :)

Comment: And now I also know why I couldn't find it with Google. I had asked for "inverse" instead of "reverse" :) :)